# Entity Framework sql Order by gives translate error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query that creates a list of this model:

```cs
public class ProductModel{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public ProductItem ProductGroep { get; set; }
    public ProductItem Product { get; set; }
    public ProductItem ProductDekking { get; set; }
    public List <ProductItem> Dekkingen { get; set; }
}

public class ProductItem {
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Naam { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public string? ProductIdNaamCombo { get; set; }
}
```

my query:

```cs
var query = (from rdk in dbContext.tblRollsDekkingens
    join pvp in dbContext.tblPremievergelijkProductens on rdk.rdk_id equals pvp.pvp_rdk_id
    join rvp in dbContext.tblRolVerzamelingProductens on pvp.pvp_id equals rvp.rvp_pvp_id
    join rpn in dbContext.tblRollsProductens on rdk.rdk_rpn_id equals rpn.rpn_id
    join cow1 in dbContext.tblCodewaardes on rvp.rvp_rolverzamelingproducten_cow_id equals cow1.cow_id
    join cow2 in dbContext.tblCodewaardes on pvp.pvp_dekking_cow_id equals cow2.cow_id
    select new ProductModel()
    {
        Id = cow1.cow_id.ToString() + "_" + rpn.rpn_id.ToString() + "_" + rdk.rdk_id.ToString(),
        ProductGroep = new ProductItem()
        {
            Id = cow1.cow_id,
            ProductId = 0,
            Naam = cow1.cow_waarde
        },
        Product = new ProductItem()
        {
            Id = rpn.rpn_id,
            ProductId = rpn.rpn_product_id,
            Naam = rpn.rpn_product_name,
            ProductIdNaamCombo = rpn.rpn_product_id.ToString() + " - " + rpn.rpn_product_name
        },
        ProductDekking = new ProductItem()
        {
            Id = rdk.rdk_id,
            ProductId = rdk.rdk_product_id,
            Naam = rdk.rdk_product_name,
            ProductIdNaamCombo = rdk.rdk_product_id.ToString() + " - " + rdk.rdk_product_name
        },
        Dekkingen = (from pvp_dek in dbContext.tblPremievergelijkProductens
            join cow_dek in dbContext.tblCodewaardes on pvp_dek.pvp_dekking_cow_id equals cow_dek.cow_id
            join rdk_dek in dbContext.tblRollsDekkingens on pvp_dek.pvp_rdk_id equals rdk_dek.rdk_id
            join rvp_dek in dbContext.tblRolVerzamelingProductens on pvp_dek.pvp_id equals rvp_dek.rvp_pvp_id
            where rdk_dek.rdk_id == rdk.rdk_id && rdk_dek.rdk_rpn_id == rpn.rpn_id && rvp_dek.rvp_rolverzamelingproducten_cow_id == cow1.cow_id
            select new ProductItem
            {
                Id = cow_dek.cow_id,
                Naam = cow_dek.cow_waarde
            }
        ).ToList()
    }
);
```

The query works great, it fills the list.
The thing is that one property is a list of items.

Basically, this provides me a list that looks like this:

productgroep, product, productdekking, Dekkingen

The last column is the one with differences.
It can have 1, 2 or 3 items.

In the database there is a record for each of those items, but I want them grouped together.

Instead of

```
productgroep1, product1, productdekking1, dekking1 
productgroep1, product1, productdekking1, dekking2
productgroep1, product1, productdekking1, dekking3
productgroep2, product2, productdekking2, dekking1
productgroep2, product2, productdekking2, dekking2
```

I want this:

```
productgroep1, product1, productdekking1, { dekking1, dekking2, dekking3 }
productgroep2, product2, productdekking2, { dekking1, dekking2 }
```

I wanted to use distinct to get this, but somehow that is not allowed.

So I tried this:

```
query = query.GroupBy(m => new { pg = m.ProductGroep, p = m.Product, pd = m.ProductDekking }).Select(m => m.First());
```

That does the same as I would expect from the distinct.

Then I wanted to do some ordering.
So I did this:

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.ProductGroep.Naam)
```

and then this:

```
producten = await query.Skip(model.FirstItem).Take(model.RowCount).ToListAsync();
```

Then I get the "Could not translate" error.

How can I do an OrderBy or OrderByDescending on this query?
Or if you can't use OrderBy after a GroupBy, is there another way to make a distinct list and then set the order?

Comment: Don't think you can group by objects. Instead, you may use the `Id` from each object (`ProductGroep`, `Product` and `ProductDekking`) to group.

Comment: That was my first attempt, but it didn't work either.